# XSLT compile error - Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported

Tags: c#, xslt, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have create new function app in .net 6.0 , I’m getting an error from XslCompiledTransform.Load once after EnableScript.
(this works fine in .net framework  4.6.1)
I'll share my code segment here for your reference.

```
private string TransformXslt(XmlReader document, string stylesheet, object[] extension,
        XSLTParams[] xsltArguments)
    {
        var transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

        transform.Load(stylesheet, new XsltSettings(true, true), null);

        var arguments = new XsltArgumentList();
        if (xsltArguments != null)
            for (var i = 0; i < xsltArguments.Length; i++)
            {
                var currentParam = xsltArguments[i];
                arguments.AddParam(currentParam.name, "", currentParam.value);
            }

        for (var index = 0; index < extension.Length; index += 2)
            arguments.AddExtensionObject(
                extension[index] as string,
                extension[index + 1]
            );

        var output = new StringBuilder();

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, transform.OutputSettings))
        {
            transform.Transform(document, arguments, writer);
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Error

[image]

This should support .net 6 as microsoft page [XslCompiledTransform.Load Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.load?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xsl-xslcompiledtransform-load(system-string-system-xml-xsl-xsltsettings-system-xml-xmlresolver))

but not sure why this failing in
transform.Load(stylesheet, new XsltSettings(true, true), null); line.

i should enable scripting
because in my xsl i have c# scrips..

[image]

Comment: You might need to use extension objects/functions instead of "script" with .NET core, that feature to embed C# is not supported.

Comment: A little follow-up on this topic, does anyone know if there is a possible work around for this? I Really need to be able to execute these templates at .net 6 :)

Comment: May I know if this was already resolved in .NET 6, or maybe a work around for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script):

> Script blocks are supported only in .NET Framework. They are **not supported** on .NET Core or **.NET 5 or later**.

Reference: [XSLT compile error-PlatformNotSupportedException: Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/449048/xslt-compile-error-platformnotsupportedexception-c.html)

Comment: I don't see this is an answer. This just seems to be a clarification on why this is not working anymore, because it is not supported anymore